# Regex Expression Mixed Fraction

Tags: java, regex, fractions

```
public class MixedNumberRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern FRACTION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\d+)\\s+)?(\\d+)/(\\d+)");

        Matcher m = FRACTION_PATTERN.matcher("1/2 + 1 1/2");

        System.out.print(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Hi, I am trying to extract out the mixed number from the string. Is my pattern expression correct?
From the example, I want the output to be "1 1/2".

I keep getting the exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
>       at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
>       at MixedNumberRegex.main(MixedNumberRegex.java:15)
>   `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your regex a bit and do it this way:

```
    Pattern FRACTION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d+\\s+)?\\d/\\d");

    Matcher m = FRACTION_PATTERN.matcher("1/2 + 1 1/2");

    while (m.find()) {
        String found = m.group();
    }
```

It will find `1/2` and `1 1/2`.

---

If you want to capture only `1 1/2`, use pattern:

```
Pattern FRACTION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\s+\\d/\\d");
```

Comment: I am still getting the no matches found exception after changing to your example pattern. :(

Comment: Do you want to always capture the second group of numbers?

Comment: Not really. Because the expression equation of the mixed number can appear anywhere for example : "1 1/2 + 1/4" or "1/4 + 1 1/2" or it can also be multiple mixed numbers in one equation for example: 

"1 1/2 + 1/4 - 1 1/8"

I want to capture all the mixed number in the equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. But the pattern will also detect 1/2 which is a normal fraction. Is there anyway to just only capture the mixed number only?

Comment: Thanks Szymon. You are a genius. Appreciate greatly for your help. :)